# how can I access the value of a stdclass in php

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I want to access the int20 and int30 in the picture below. how can i do it?

here is my var_dump result:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[238]
          public 'time' => int 20
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[242]
          public 'time' => int 30
```

and here is my query:

```
$sum_time = array();
foreach ($a as $f) {
    $sum_time[] = DB::select("select time from quiz where '$f'=id");
}        
var_dump($sum_time);
```

Comment: On the stdclass use -> so for example time in your case $theObject->time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your code to get an array of all the "time" values

```
$times = array();
foreach ($sum_time as $value) {
    $times[] = $value[0]->time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $sum_time = array();
    $time = array();
    $count=0;
    foreach ($a as $f) {
        $sum_time[] = DB::select("select time from quiz where '$f'=id");
        $time[]=$sum_time[$count]->time;
        $count++;
    }   
print_r($time)     
    var_dump($sum_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, it looks like a typical [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

If we assume that the question is *how do I retrieve the `time` property?*, the answer is:

For arrays, you use the `[]` operator:

```
$arr = array(
    'time' => 20
);

var_dump($arr['time']);
/* 
will return:
  int(20)
*/
```

For objects, you use the `->` operator:

```
// Can be achieved aso with "new stdClass()";
$myObj = (object) array(
    'time' => 20
);

var_dump($myObj);
/*
Will return:
  object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
    ["time"]=>
    int(20)
  }
*/

var_dump($myObj->time);
/* 
will return:
  int(20)
*/
```

Anyway, for future cases, it is important to give some background, it might be possible that the solution for the real problem does not even include this question....

Answer (score -1):

You can use `->object` to stdClass.
Ex.

```
$v = new StdClass();
$v->name = "Mohsen";
$v->addr = "somewhere";

$tmp = array("data" => "other data","detail" => $v);
var_dump($tmp);

echo "<br /><br />";
echo $tmp["detail"]->name; // Access your stdClass object
```